# Android Studio could load file contents correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

i interested to know why my android studio couldn't load file content correctly? this is simple screen shot as what happened for my application

[image]

is anybody could help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read [**`Mismatched Encoding`**](http://tools.android.com/knownissues/encoding)

> The encoding used to compile your project is specified in the
>   build.gradle files. The default, which is used when no specific
>   encoding is specified, is UTF-8. We strongly recommend you use UTF-8
>   encoding whenever possible.

**File -> Settings->** Search -> **File Encoding->Global Encoding->UTF-8**

[image]

Comment: i think problem solved and i should check more, but i accepted and upvoted your post, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an encoding issue. In Android Studio the encoding is set to `UTF-8`, but I don't see it specified in Notepad. In Notepad, use the `Save As` dialog and set the `Encoding` dropdown to `UTF-8`. It should then load properly in Android Studio.