# File loaded in wrong encoding UTF-8 , Reload in windows- 1252 android studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I'm working on project having multiple Git branches.After switching to different branch , few java & Kotlin source files are fine and few are showing encoded source files, even when I build and run project it work fine.
I'm getting below error message while trying to load these files.

> file was loaded in wrong encoding UTF-8
>
> package directive does not match file location.

and sometimes it also gets stuck. It was working fine with other branches.

I tried few hacks like , clean/rebuild / delete build folder, etc but still of no use.

I'm unable to see my java , Kotlin  &  xml code but when I open these files in notepad it work fine.

[image: SAME 1]

[image: settiings]

[image: View1]

Comment: That doesn't look like a source file at all, it seems to be a class file. The errors you see  are red herrings, the real problem is that whatever you view is not a source file.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61390848/3395198

Comment: @JoachimSauer have a look at updated pictures

Comment: @AtifAbbAsi: you've blanked out so much content that this image doesn't contain substantially more information than the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

so what I did was I added the below piece of code in my Gradle file **compile options**, cleaned the project, and invalidate and restarted android studio.

```
compileOptions {
    
    compileOptions.encoding = 'windows-1251' //'UTF-8'
}
```